# Android Content Provider Query returning true when it should be false

Tags: android, sqlite

I am fairly new to android development and I am trying to insert into a table using content provider and then check the table and retrieve the record if it exists. It continues to say that it exists BUT it is not the record that i was searching for.

```
            Cursor c = contentResolver.query(ContentDescriptor.Survey.CONTENT_URI, projection, 
                ContentDescriptor.Survey.Cols.SURVEYNAME + " =?", new String[] {surveyName}, null);
        if((c != null) && (c.moveToFirst())){
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //what if it does exist do something here
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Survey Already Exists " + surveyName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent().setClass(CreateSurveyActivity.this, PickSurveyActivity.class);              
        }
        else{
            //does not exist in database
            survey = SurveyRepository.instance().createNewSurvey(context, surveyName);
            Log.i(TAG, "survey did not exist creating survey");
            SurveyRepository.instance().loadContent(context);
        }
        c.close();
    }
```

Comment: post your contentProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `query` method, you are not putting the selection in the query you make.

Hence, `SURVEYNAME + " =?"` is ignored.

You need to call something like :

```
return builder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
```

to pass your arguments to your database.

Comment: would i have to use another URI with the path_for_id_token or the same content URI would work. i added the return builder statement to the query method. Class posted under orignal post edit.

Comment: Ok i think i got it.. code is still f#$#ing up but i think i should be able to implement it the way i want. thank you for your help njzk2